# Error in my PDO fetch column function

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am using PDO object for executing query in php .

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('select email from users where email = :email');
return (bool) $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email))->fetchColumn();
```

I am getting error here .

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object

what is the problem please help , `$this->db->query()` command is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, it's spelled "execute", not "exectute"

Secondly, `PDOStatement::execute` returns a boolean indicating whether or not the query succeeded. To fetch results, you must call a fetch method on the original statement instance.

Comment: hi if i added the fetchcolumn() then it give me error as in question please check

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php - execute returns bool. If you want to access the results you should, in new line, type: `return $stmt->fetchColumn()`

Answer (score 1):

You have spelt **execute** wrong.

Comment: hi if i added the fetchcolumn() then it give me error as in question please check