# PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to move to PDO can't figure out what is wrong with this

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE repo=? AND list=? AND email=?";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$res = $q->execute(array($repo, $list, $email));
$v = $res->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: [How to squeeze error message out of PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3726505)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in my PDO fetch column function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407413/error-in-my-pdo-fetch-column-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDOStatement::execute()` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE` (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)), so `$res` is being set to a boolean and then you're trying to call a method on it.  Try this instead:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE repo=? AND list=? AND email=?";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
if (($res = $q->execute(array($repo, $list, $email))) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Query failed!';
    exit;
}
$v = $q->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )
it doesn't return mixed value, only boolean value.

Comment: (trying to make a note on this)So the $dbh is an database object $q is a statement object which, once executed, has the resultset hung on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$q->execute(...)
```

Returns only boolean value.
Proper way:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);

if ($q->execute($repo, $list, $email) == TRUE) {
 $v = $q->fetchColumn();
} else {
 //error
}
```