# How to call procedure with select command using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the below procedure with the purpose of selecting the base column where it contains a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMap(p_team VARCHAR(100) CHARSET 'utf8')
BEGIN
SELECT Base FROM map WHERE 
map.Base = p_team OR
Ver1 = p_team OR
Ver2 = p_team OR
Ver3 = p_team OR
Ver4 = p_team OR
Ver5 = p_team OR
Ver6 = p_team OR
Ver7 = p_team OR
Ver8 = p_team OR
Ver9 = p_team OR
Ver10 = p_team OR
Ver11 = p_team OR
Ver12 = p_team;
end //
```

When I try to call procedure from PHP like this :

```
function getMap($data){
    $query = $this->PDO->prepare("CALL GetMap(:data)");
    $query->bindParam(':data', $data);

    $ex = $query->execute();
    $res = $ex->fetchColumn();
    echo $res;
    if($res){
        return $res;
    }
    else
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

It returns an exception:

> Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object

How can I get Base column as a variable from the select procedure?

Comment: Yes it's returns Base column from map table where condition is true...

So when i call CALL GetMap('Haka'); it returns me base value:
Haka Valkeakoski in Workbench

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948151/pdo-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetchcolumn-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) on the return value from execute and that, as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), is a boolean value.

The method needs to be called on an instance of the [PDOStatement](http://php.net/PDOStatement) class, so in your case the **$query** variable

That means

```
$res = $query->fetchColumn();
```

instead of

```
$res = $ex->fetchColumn();
```